# Whatsapp-Restore from iCloud is not showing my Backup

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, restore, whatsapp.app

10 days back, I've made a backup of Whatsapp and then I uninstalled the application and Signed out of iCloud to give my iPhone 6 to my friend.

Now when I signed back into iCloud and installed Whatsapp again and gave my same old number, Restore from iCloud saying **"No Backup found"**.

But I can see the Whatsapp backup of 540MB in *Settings> iCloud> Manage Storage> Backups*. It has messages from more than a year that I'm saving it.

I *never* came across this situation earlier while reinstalling.

I've *enough storage space* to restore and I tried with connecting to the *Wi-Fi* and *Mobile data*.

My current iOS version is **10.3.1** from more than a month.

Any help or suggestion to get back my backup would be highly appreciated. what should I do now?

Thanks million

Comment: Did you read and follow https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201351 before  giving your iPhone away?

Comment: I didn't read, but I've followed the same procedure except "Backup your device" and I don't need to erase the whole data coz I've given it to my friend only. 
How come this effects my problem? I didn't face this issue earlier, with the same procedure followed.

Comment: i have the same problem mention above. I switched from iphone 6 to iphone x. the phone number is the same , the phone name is the same and the back up is there cause 3th party software do find it and it's also visible in the phone itsself in Settings> iCloud> Manage Storage> Backups.
But still when installing whats up it doesnt find any backup.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your phone name from Settings > general > About > Name and make sure the new iPhone's name as same as before. After reboot/restart WhatsApp you will able to find the backup.

Comment: I can confirm that the phone name matters. Didn't find this information anywhere else. Thanks