# Restoring WhatsApp backup from iCloud Drive

Tags: ios, restore, whatsapp.app

I have a problem with restoring iCloud WhatsApp backup on my new iPhone.

Some time ago I created WhatsApp iCloud backup and then sold the phone.
I've bought a new iPhone, inserted the same sim-card, signed in the same Apple ID account.

When I open WhatsApp app it tries to find my iCloud backup and always says that no backup found.

I have read that question: [Accessing WhatsApp iCloud backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365950/accessing-whatsapp-icloud-backup) and have found all .icloud files on my Macbook. But I don't understand how I can import them on new phone.

Moreover, I've read that: [Whatsapp-Restore from iCloud is not showing my Backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284657/whatsapp-restore-from-icloud-is-not-showing-my-backup). I've already checked that my new iPhone has the same name as the previous one.

PS: The first thing I did is writing to WhatsApp support. They have answers like "we cant help you with data restoring".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is basically a [customer support question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) which should be addressed to WhatsApp directly.

Comment: The first thing I did is writing to whatsapp support. They have answers like "we cant help you with data restoring"

Answer (score 0):

I'm was in the same boat as you Viktor.

You're only missing some steps to be able to get your *actual* backup files. The `*.icloud` files are all 2kb in size and don't contain any data but are rather links to the actual files.

On your macOS go into `Settings > Apple ID` and make sure to **disable** the `Optimise Mac Storage` option as that would give you access to the real files.

After that wait a bit as your computer would need to apply the changes and updates, restart if possible, then when you access the `~/Library/Mobile Documents` directory you can see that the files are now mostly `*.tar` extensions which can be copied now.

Hopefully that sorts you out!